# PrimeNG pie chart randomly displays, and displays on change of resolution

Tags: angular, charts, chart.js, primeng

I am using primeng pie chart with dynamic data from back-end. While I was using static data, the pie chart was working as expected, but now after integration with dynamic data, It displays randomly upon page refresh. It renders and displays itself upon change of screen resolution, i.e. width and height. Have tried multiple methods like ViewChild, responsiveness and setting height and width for chart but none seem to work.

[chart as default](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cZM1.png)

[chart after I clicked toggle device toolbar in dev console and un-clicked it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axTvq.png)

Answer (score 0):

I remember facing the similar issues. It's related to the change detection. The screen resolution change triggers the change detection. As well as some event like mouse movement if you have some handlers for this events anywhere.

Considering I don't see the code, I imagine there might be two solutions:

- The data binding could be done without changing the reference to the variable with data. e.g. using push method to update the data source.

```
// this is not recognized by the change detection mechanism as update because the reference to this.data is not updated
this.resourceService.getResources().subscribe( data => { 
  var counts1 = {};
  this.chartHistory.forEach((x) => {
    counts1[x] = (counts1[x] || 0)+1; 
  });
  for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(counts1).length; i++) {
    this.chartHistoryData.push(Object.keys(counts1)[i]);
    this.chartHistoryVal.push(Object.values(counts1)[i]);
  }
});

// this would be recognized
this.resourceService.getResources().subscribe( data => { 
  var counts1 = {};
  this.chartHistory.forEach((x) => {
    counts1[x] = (counts1[x] || 0)+1; 
  });
  Object.entries(counts1).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    this.chartHistoryData = [...this.chartHistoryData, key];
    this.chartHistoryVal = [...this.chartHistoryVal, value];
  });
});
```

- As a workaround triggering the change detection after data update could work as well. [ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectorRef#!#detectChanges-anchor) does it

Comment: `code` this.resourceService.getResources().subscribe(
      data => { var counts1 = {};
        this.chartHistory.forEach(function(x) { counts1[x] = (counts1[x] || 0)+1; });
        for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(counts1).length; i++) {
          this.chartHistoryData.push(Object.keys(counts1)[i]);
          this.chartHistoryVal.push(Object.values(counts1)[i]);
        } `code`  I am pushing objects from a json into the value and data array for chart

Comment: Tried the 2nd option, but is breaking down a sidebar functionality "ViewDestroyedError: Attempt to use a destroyed view: detectChanges".

Comment: THat would be quite hard to debug. I updated the first option with you code sample and changed the `for` loop for more short version